# Ubuntu installation on UEFI system - grub console after boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After a short (but bloody) battle I was finally able to install Ubuntu on my Dell XPS 13 (the 2015 one).

After rebooting all I can see is the grub console. Typing `exit` pops up the Windows system that was pre-installed (yes, I want a dual boot).

I have no idea what to do with this, I'm no grub expert... What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I think you made a mistake during installation.  What option have you selected under the section "Device for boot loader installation"?

Comment: @Hunter - I wasnt selecting anything... I made two partitions under WIndows (one for / and one for /home), I made a bootable USB with Ubuntu, I've booted the installator from the pendrive, went through the installation process, in the installation method I've chosen manual partiotioning, I've selected one partiotion for / one for /home, and I've installed the system. I wasnt asked for a selection "Device for boot loader installation"...

Comment: If by "grub console" you mean a text-mode prompt that reads "grub>", then that means that GRUB is installed but is also badly misconfigured or Ubuntu itself is badly damaged. It's possible that Boot Repair will fix it, but that's far from certain. The output from Boot Repair (as requested by oldfred) may be helpful in diagnosing the problem. It's possible that rEFInd (as suggested by Shades) may help, but that will work only if the installation is basically sound and the only problem is with GRUB. (If the Ubuntu installation is damaged, rEFInd won't help.)

Answer (score 0):

Install reFind... http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/ 
It handles and does all that for ya :P