# GRUB console loading on 2 disk dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

Ok.I have windows 10 installed on my computer by default, and I have followed the advice of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option). When I have the 2nd disc (disk? If you can answer that question too that would be great :P) plugged in, it works fine. However when this disc/k is not attached, I simply see a grub console. I understand that the first stage of grub gets installed there, my question is **how can I make it boot directly to windows 10?**

Thanks for your time,

Ben

N.B. My apologies if this is a duplicate, but to the best of my ability (not much) it is not. Also, please right your answer very simply, as I am not very clever.

Comment: Pardon me, I have found a duplicate of my question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/627114/ubuntu-installation-on-uefi-system-grub-console-after-boot), but I do not know how to use "rEFInd". Do I run it on windows or ubuntu, how do I install it, is there another option not requiring 3rd party software?

Comment: No need for third party software. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair: help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info - DO NOT apply any correction yet, just post the resulting boot info. We can troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Ok, making that now.

Comment: @BenStankovich, I believe he means for you to follow the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info.

Comment: Got it, http://paste2.org/taH0zPA3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a mix of UEFI and Legacy installs:

- `=> Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
  => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.`

and at the same time an apparently normal ESP (EFI system partition) for Windows/Linux dual boot.

Ubuntu is installed in sdc (not "drive K" - Windows own terminology is irrelevant here), the 2TB HDD, but in UEFI mode you should boot from sda, the 120GB SDD(?).
Make sure you have set the correct boot device at UEFI and then:

1. You can choose the Windows bootloader as the default in the settings -> Boots directly to Windows; or
2. You can choose Ubuntu -> Boots to GRUB menu from where you can boot Ubuntu or Windows.

If option 2 boots directly to Ubuntu, open a Terminal, input the following command and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that part of the file means. My pc came with win 8, which I upgraded to 10 ages ago. My UEFI BIOS settings put the 2TB drive first (well, the stage 1 grub leading to the 2TB drive). When that drive is unplugged (it's external) that grub tries to load Ubuntu, fails, and reverts to a terminal. Typing "exit" ends that terminal and win 10 loads. What I want to know is how to make grub know that if it can't find the drive, automatically exit so win 10 boots. To recap: I want the grub "OS picking menu" to load when the drive is in, and when it is not, go straight to win 10.

Comment: There's no easy way to do that with an external drive. Perhaps @oldfred can suggest something. But again, it should be easy to change the default boot drive at the UEFI settings.

Comment: I know what I'll do! I can put the Windows first, and then, when I want Ubuntu, plug in the drive and chose it as a temporary boot device. Given you helped me so much, I'll accept your answer. Thanks